# You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command

Tags: angular

I am trying to run a drag and drop sample from [dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula).but when i run `ng serve` it complains with :

```
You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.
```

when i run `ng -v` in my machine, I have:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
node: 4.6.0
os: win32 x64
```

I have tried to add:

```
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
```

in the dependencies of project and then `npm install`, but my node fails to install the package.

**How can i run the** [dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula)?

Comment: You can find out how to install and use the Angular CLI here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run the dragula demo.

Apparently dragula was not created using an angular cli project. So running the `ng serve` command from the demo folder will not yield any results.

Instead you should run the application using node.

First update your angular CLI to make sure it is the most recent version.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

or

```
yarn global add @angular/cli@latest
```

Next install all dependencies by executing `npm install` or `npm i` from the directory you downloaded the package to. This downloads and installs all the dependencies mentioned in the package.json file and their dependencies.

Then you can run the development build by using the `npm start` command. This will transpile the typescript and creates a webpack that can be accessed using the url given in the console (`http://localhost:4200` by default). You could also try to use the `ng serve` command again.

Comment: Updating angular-cli via the command above and then running `ng serve` worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

if `ng serve` doesn't work try `npm start`.

I don't know the exact reason, but for me it works !!

Answer (score 14):

Try installing `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` since the **angular-cli** has been renamed.

Comment: I encountered the issue where I could successfully use `npm start` but trying `ng serve` would result in OP error. This solved that for me.

Answer (score 4):

**ng serve** Will not work if you don't have angular cli,

but you can start your project by **npm start** command.

You should install angular cli globally by following command.

**npm install -g @angular/cli@latest**

Answer (score 1):

> angular-cli and @angular-cli is different so that the version becomes conflict. So try this commands. Hope this helps for you

```
1. npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular-cli
2. npm cache clean --force
3. npm install -g @angular-cli or npm install -g @angular-cli@latest
```

Comment: I get the error "Invalid package name "@angular-cli": name can only contain URL-friendly characters" running the last command, for both.

Comment: This will be `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

`

Answer (score 1):

A quick hint is `angular-cli vs angular/cli` is different. if you by mistake installed angular-cli remove it and install angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle to the directory of your project, i.e. root folder of the project.
ex.
`PS E:\workspace\Angular dev\Heroes> ng serve`
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

```
PS E:\workspace\Angular dev\Heroes> cd tour-heroes
PS E:\workspace\Angular dev\Heroes\tour-heroes> ng serve
```

> Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open
>   your browser on http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest --force
```

This overrides the current version.